# Get values of cell row beside it only otherwise have a blank cell & formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Is there a way preferably through excel formulas but also VBA to get the cell next to it and and if there is no value return a blank?  If there is a value return that given number. Blank as in no data in it not even a =A1

In an example
Column A has a formula which gives 1, 2, 3 each row downwards.  In column B I have formula which gets the value next to it (A1, A2 etc,) but it only appears blank and the formula is still there.

I also know how to simply copy and paste special which could be deemed a workaround but I am just curious if there is a better way of doing this.

```
  Sub CopyCol()

        Sheets("Sheet3").Columns(10).Copy

        Sheets("Sheet3").Columns(10).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried changing the Number Format of column B to ;;; (three semi-colons) ? Column B will still store you formula but will not show its value.

Comment: @RomcelGeluz Have I tried changing the number format to ;;; in excel?  I just tried it then and it looks like that just returns blanks for all B column cells but the formula remains in tact.  I want something like =A1 and if there is no value in the cell to the left then it just gives no formula & blank

Comment: You really need VBA with this task. Give me a minute or two to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyCol()
    Dim ur As Range, col1 As Variant, col2 As Variant, r As Long

    Set ur = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").UsedRange

    ur.Columns("B").Clear
    col2 = ur.Columns("B")
    col1 = ur.Columns("A")

    If Not IsEmpty(col1) Then
        If IsArray(col1) Then
            For r = 1 To UBound(col1)
                If Len(col1(r, 1)) > 0 Then col2(r, 1) = col1(r, 1)
            Next
        Else
            col2 = col1
        End If
        ur.Columns("B") = col2
    End If
End Sub
```